# How to run GridSearchCV inside RFECV?

Tags: python, gridsearchcv

I would like to write a script to select most important features using RFECV. The estimator I want to use is logistic regression. In addition, I also want to do the GridSearchCV. In other words, I want to tune the parameters first using GridSearchCV and then update the parameters in each iterations of RFECV.
I have written a code below but I'm not sure when I use RFECV(GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression)), the parameters of the model is tuned and updated in each iterations of RFECV or not. Please give me some advices on this issue.
Thank you so much!

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterGrid, StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import numpy as np

X,y = make_classification(n_samples =50,
                          n_features=5,
                          n_informative=3,
                          n_redundant=0,
                          random_state=0)

class GridSeachWithCoef(GridSearchCV):
    @property
    def coef_(self):
        return self.best_estimator_.coef_


solvers = ['lbfgs', 'liblinear']
penalty = ['l1', 'l2']
c_values = np.logspace(-4, 4, 20)
param_grid = [
    {'penalty' : penalty,
    'C': c_values,
    'solver': solvers}
]

GS = GridSeachWithCoef(LogisticRegression(), param_grid = param_grid, cv = 3, verbose=True, n_jobs=-1)
min_features_to_select = 1  # Minimum number of features to consider
rfecv = RFECV(
    estimator=GS, cv=3, scoring = "accuracy"
)
rfecv.fit(X, y)
print("Optimal number of features : %d" % rfecv.n_features_)
```

(the code above was adopted from other people in the forum. Thank you for your code)